# Handling a hover event for a google charts table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to trigger a javascript method when the mouse hovers over a row in a google chart table?

I can see there are examples of doing this for a bar chart for example, but I tried the same event on a table and nothing happened.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Table visualization does not support mouseover events.  You can attach regular javascript event handlers to the table rows, though.  Here's an example that uses jQuery to attach a mouseover event handler to the table rows:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    $('#table_div tr').mouseover(function (e) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Edit:

if you want to get the row/column information from the cells, this is how you do it:

```
// data is the DataTable
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
        data.setProperty(i, j, 'className', 'row_' + i + ' column_' + j);
    }
}

// create the event handler on the <td>'s
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    $('#table_div td').mouseover(function (e) {
        var row, column;
        var classNames = this.className;
        var match = classNames.match(/row_(\d)+/i);
        if (match.length > 1) {
            row = match[1];
        }
        match = classNames.match(/column_(\d)+/i);
        if (match.length > 1) {
            column = match[1];
        }

        if (row != null) {
            // then we have moused over a data row
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there an easy way of getting the row number (like the select event gives)?

Comment: Not really.  You can work around it to an extent by setting the "className" property of each cell in the DataTable to indicate the row number, and use a mouseover event listener on the <td>'s instead.  You can grab the row information from the <td>'s className attribute.  I'll edit my answer with example code.